# Create lnk shortcut from lua (without lfs)

Tags: io, lua, lnk

I would like to write a function to create a windows .lnk file from my lua script. I found a function in the LuaFileSystem [library](https://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/manual.html) . Is there a way to do this without the library? (The reason: I am writing the script for multiple users, would be nice if we don't have to install the library on every machine.)

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Do you need symlink to a file of shortcut (with an icon) to a file?

Comment: I doubt that "lfs" library can make a shortcut on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a shortcut (an .lnk file)

```
-- your .lnk file
local your_shortcut_name = "your_shortcut.lnk"      

-- target (file or folder) with full path
local your_target_filespec = [[C:\Windows\notepad.exe]]

local ps = io.popen("powershell -command -", "w")
ps:write("$ws = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell;$s = $ws.CreateShortcut('"..your_shortcut_name.."');$s.TargetPath = '"..your_target_filespec.."';$s.Save()")
ps:close()
```

---

To make a symlink simply use `os.execute"mklink ..."`

Answer (score 0):

Use luacom is faster than powershell

```lua
local luacom=require'luacom'
local shortcut_file_path='test_create_shortcut.lnk'
local target_file_path=arg[0]
local shellObject=luacom.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
local shortcut=shellObject:CreateShortcut(shortcut_file_path)
shortcut.TargetPath=target_file_path
shortcut:Save()
assert(io.open(shortcut_file_path)):close()--shortcut file exist now
os.remove(shortcut_file_path)
```

And use [FileSystemObject object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object) (another COM), or [Windows shell link file format spec for Kaitai Struct](https://formats.kaitai.io/windows_lnk_file/) (parse binary file struct to get info on various file format) to retrieve shortcut info. Which 'lfs' can't do now.

see: [Create a desktop shortcut with Windows Script Host - Windows Client | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/admin-development/create-desktop-shortcut-with-wsh)
[LuaCOM User Manual (Version 1.3)](https://web.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/%7Ercerq/luacom/pub/1.3/luacom-htmldoc/luacom.html)